# Using Object Prototype in a Form to Create Multiple Users in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

(Beginner) I'm working on a form for a course project that will create a new object each time I fill out this form. I created an object prototype that checks out. I tested in the console using:

```
var nick = new diner('Nick', 'Chicken', 5, 'Rice', 3);
```

... it all checks out and a new object is created.

But how can I create a brand new object with each form submission?

```
<script>

  //this works in the console when I call it to create a new object. Ex., var nick = new diner('nick', 'chicken', 5, 'rice', 3);

  function diner(name, mealOne, mealOnePrice, mealTwo, mealTwoPrice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mealOne = mealOne;
    this.mealOnePrice = mealOnePrice;
    this.mealTwo = mealTwo;
    this.mealTwoPrice = mealTwoPrice;
    this.total = function() {
        return this.mealOnePrice + this.mealTwoPrice;
    };
    this.tax = function() {
        return this.total() * .1;
    };
}

</script>

<body>

  <h1>Meal Calculator</h1>
  <label>Enter Diner Name:<input type='text' id='name'></label>
  <br>
  <label>What are they eating?<input type='text' id='mealOne'></label>
  <br>
  <label>How much is it?<input type='text' id='mealOnePrice'></label>
  <br>
  <label>What else are they eating?<input type='text' id='mealTwo'></label>
  <br>
  <label>How much is that?<input type='text' id='mealTwoPrice'></label>
  <br>

  //I think it's this diner() function that's not quite right

  <button type="button" onclick="diner()">Build Diner Object</button>

</body>
```

Ultimately I'd like to call the new object(s) and see:

```
nick;
diner {name: "nick", mealOne: "chicken", mealOnePrice: 5, mealTwo: "rice", mealTwoPrice: 3}
```

UPDATE** I'm much closer now, but I'm still getting this uncaught reference error:

```
<script>

  function diner(name, mealOne, mealOnePrice, mealTwo, mealTwoPrice) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mealOne = mealOne;
    this.mealOnePrice = mealOnePrice;
    this.mealTwo = mealTwo;
    this.mealTwoPrice = mealTwoPrice;
    this.total = function() {
        return this.mealOnePrice + this.mealTwoPrice;
    };
    this.tax = function() {
        return this.total() * .1;
    };
  }

  var name;
  var mealOne;
  var mealOnePrice;
  var mealTwo;
  var mealTwoPrice;

  function buildObj() {
    name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    mealOne = document.getElementById('mealOne').value;
    mealOnePrice = document.getElementById('mealOnePrice').value;
    mealTwo = document.getElementById('mealTwo').value;
    mealTwoPrice = document.getElementById('mealTwoPrice').value;
    name = new diner(name, mealOne, mealOnePrice, mealTwo, mealTwoPrice);
  }

</script>

<body>

  <form id="id" action="action">
    <h1>Meal Calculator</h1>
    <label>Enter Diner Name:<input type='text' id='name'></label>
    <br>
    <label>What are they eating?<input type='text' id='mealOne'></label>
    <br>
    <label>How much is it?<input type='text' id='mealOnePrice'></label>
    <br>
    <label>What else are they eating?<input type='text' id='mealTwo'></label>
    <br>
    <label>How much is that?<input type='text' id='mealTwoPrice'></label>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="buildObj()">Build Diner Object</button>
  </form>

</body>
```

Comment: `<form>` element does not appear at `html` at Question ?

Comment: First you need to prevent the form from submitting, or else your javascript doesn't have anything to work with when a new page is loaded right away.

Comment: What are you going to do with those objects when you have created them? Only `console.log()` them, and then forget them?

Comment: I'm going to use the values to calculate tax and tip on a meal. But I'm having trouble creating separate diner objects. It's just a course project so I don't know how far I'll go with it.

Comment: @nick - many people spent their time assisting you with this question, but you didn't take the time to mark a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `onclick` handler in your HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="diner()">Build Diner Object</button>
```

I recommend you adding an intermediate function that handles the `click` event and creates a new `diner` object:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="onclick()">Build Diner Object</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function onclick() {
    // create the new object
    var nick = new diner('nick', 'chicken', 5, 'rice', 3);

   // ... do what you want with it
}
```

I also would suggest adding a `form` element around your fields:

```
<body>
  <form id="id" action="action">
    <h1>Meal Calculator</h1>
    <label>Enter Diner Name:<input type='text' id='name'></label>
    <br>
    <label>What are they eating?<input type='text' id='mealOne'></label>
    <br>
    <label>How much is it?<input type='text' id='mealOnePrice'></label>
    <br>
    <label>What else are they eating?<input type='text' id='mealTwo'></label>
    <br>
    <label>How much is that?<input type='text' id='mealTwoPrice'></label>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="onclick()">Build Diner Object</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to keep creating diner objects? In other words, fill out the form, click the button, and a new object is made. I updated the post so you can see what I've done after getting some advice. Still getting a reference error though.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep creating"?  Do you mean stopping the browser from sending a `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing the portion that would traverse the DOM elements, gathering their values to pass to diner(). While this *can* be done with vanilla JS, there's a good reason developers tend to favor using a utility library (like jquery).

You're going to need something like this:

```
function submit(){
    diner(
        document.getElementById('name').value,
        document.getElementById('mealOne').value,
        document.getElementById('mealOnePrice').value,
        document.getElementById('mealTwo').value,
        document.getElementById('mealTwoPrice').value
    );
}
```

Then you'd call *that* function from your submit button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="submit()">Build Diner Object</button>
```

Comment: Oops, you are calling diner as a regular function, you forgot `new`

Answer (score 0):

In your event handler for the button, you are calling `diner()` (calling it like a regular function) but should be calling `new diner(...)` (as a constructor) retrieving the values from the form. See http://js-bits.blogspot.com/2010/08/constructors-without-using-new.html

A more decoupled way is to set the handler through JavaScript instead of through html attributes.

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    // same pattern for all parameters
    var dinerX = new diner(name, ...)
```

});

Comment: Don't forget `.value`

Comment: Juan, I tried this and was still getting a reference error. I updated the post. Let me know if you have any thoughts.